# Best way to handle sparse + non-sparse data to create a model

Tags: r, scikit-learn, sparse-matrix, estimation

I'm wondering what is the best way to handle sparse+non-sparse data in e.g. a Ridge regression using scikit learn.

Ridge can handle both sparse and nonsparse data.

Imagine something simple as a `description` (text) field that gets Count/Tdidf Vectorized (sparse), and an `income` continuous variable.

Now imagine that we have several other text fields and several other continuous variables.

What is the best way to model some continuous `y` variable?

I've considered making two separate models (one using sparse data, one using non-sparse) and somehow trying to combine.

I've also considered using PCA to make the sparse data into a "handleable" amount of continuous features.

How do you usually solve this issue?

Note: the continuous variables would have many unique values (and you'd lose power anyway when converting continuous to bins), and the text fields might end up having like a million features, thus not able to be dense.

Answer (score -1):

this reply may be a little out of context, but i want to understand by "Ridge can handle both sparse and no-sparse data"? I am trying to run a logistic regression model in R which has all text fields, however, my dependent variable is very sparse. Only .9%. Do you think Ridge would be good algo to implement?